# What's the source for unanimous decision of the Sanhedrin?

Tags: sanhedrin

I often hear that if the Sanhedrin were to vote unanimously to condemn an accused then the verdict is that he goes free. What is the original source for this?

Answer (score 4):

[Sanhedrin 17a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.17a.20?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) is the original source, here elucidated by R Steinsalt

> Rav Kahana says: In a Sanhedrin where all the judges saw fit to
> convict the defendant in a case of capital law, they acquit him. The
> Gemara asks: What is the reasoning for this halakha? It is since it is
> learned as a tradition that suspension of the trial overnight is
> necessary in order to create a possibility of acquittal. The halakha
> is that they may not issue the guilty verdict on the same day the
> evidence was heard, as perhaps over the course of the night one of the
> judges will think of a reason to acquit the defendant. And as those
> judges all saw fit to convict him they will not see any further
> possibility to acquit him, because there will not be anyone arguing
> for such a verdict. Consequently, he cannot be convicted.

The Rambam ([MT Sanhedrin 9:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_The_Sanhedrin_and_the_Penalties_within_their_Jurisdiction.9.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) explains it further

> When all the judges of a Sanhedrin begin
> their judgment of a case involving capital punishment and say that the
> defendant is liable, he is exonerated. There must be some who seek to
> exonerate him and argue on his behalf, but yet the majority hold him
> liable. Only then he is executed.

Comment: Fascinating idea. We don't approve of "no-brainers".

Comment: Beautiful. If I may attempt a paraphrased? "70 great Jews got together to review accusations against a fellow Jew and not a single one of them could even _think_ of a possible way to acquit him? Something fishy is going on"